# Object Oriented Python for area of triangle

Tags: python-3.x

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tIARv.jpg)Write a Python Program(with class concepts) to find the area of the triangle using the below
formula.

```
area = (s*(s-a)*(s-b)*(s-c)) ** 0.5
```

Function to take the length of the sides of triangle from user should be defined in the parent
class and function to calculate the area should be defined in subclass.

in the image the code that i have tried. but getting error. please help.``

`

```
class poly:
    def _init_(self,a,b,c):
        self.a = float(a)
        self.b = float(b)
        self.c = float(c)
a= input("a=")
b= input("b=")
c= input("c=")

class triangle(poly):
    def get_area(self):
        s = (a + b + c) / 2
        return (s*(s-a)*(s-b)*(s-c)) ** 0.5        

t = triangle(a,b,c)
print("area : {}".format(t.area()))
```

`

Comment: post the code the you have tried before asking the question. This is not the site write  code for you

Comment: i have tried to do but some errors happen and i am new to stack overflow kind of forum so didn't know how should i ask people, that's why i posted the ques only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class poly:
    def __init__(self,a,b,c):
        self.a = float(a)
        self.b = float(b)
        self.c = float(c)
a= int(input("a="))
b= int(input("b="))
c= int(input("c="))

class triangle(poly):
    def __init__(self,a,b,c):
        super().__init__(a,b,c)

    def get_area(self):
        s = (a + b + c) / 2
        return (s*(s-a)*(s-b)*(s-c)) ** 0.5        

t = triangle(a,b,c)
print("area : {}".format(t.get_area()))
```

I noticed a lot of errors. First **__init__** has two underscores( _ ) and not one. In python 3 input *returns a string so you need to typecast to int* before doing arithmetic operations,else you will get TypeError. Third you did not call **init** method to reference the superclass. Last the function you wrote is **get_area** and not **area**.

Hope so it solves your problem. Welcome to Stackoverflow!!

Comment: yes it solved my problem,  and thanking you for let me know where i made the mistake

Answer (score 0):

```
w = 2
h = 4
area = 0.5 * (w * h)
print('the area of a triangle with a width of 2 and a height of 4 is ' + area)
```

that is how to make python find the area of a triangle

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```py
class poly:
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        self.a = float(a)
        self.b = float(b)
        self.c = float(c)
        self.area = 0

class triangle(poly):
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        poly.__init__(self, a, b, c)

    def calculate_area(self):
        s = (self.a + self.b + self.c) / 2
        self.area = float((s * (s - self.a) * (s - self.b) * (s - self.c))) ** 0.5

    def get_area(self):
        return self.area     

a, b, c = input("a = "), input("b = "), input("c = ")

t = triangle(a, b, c)
t.calculate_area()
print("area : {}".format(t.get_area()))
```

Comment: Thanking You it is Working.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
class geometry:
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        self.a = float(input("a = "))
        self.b = float(input("a = "))
        self.c = float(input("a = "))
        

class triangle(geometry):
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        super().__init__(a, b, c)

    def area_triangle(self):
        s = (self.a + self.b + self.c) / 2
        return  float((s * (s - self.a) * (s - self.b) * (s - self.c))) ** 0.5

t = triangle(a, b, c) 
print("area : {}".format(t.area_triangle()))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Sides:
    def __init__(self,a, b, c):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c
        
class A(Sides):
    def area(self):
        s = (self.a + self.b + self.c)/2
        return (s*(s-self.a)*(s-self.b)*(s-self.c)) ** 0.5

t = A(20,30,40)

print("area of Triangle : {}".format(t.area()))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class sides:
    def __init__(self,a,b,c):
        self.a=a
        self.b=b
        self.c=c
        
class triangle(sides):
    def area(self):
        s=(self.a+self.b+self.c)*0.5
        return float((s * (s - self.a) * (s - self.b) * (s - self.c))) ** 0.5

a, b, c = float(input("a = ")), float(input("b = ")), float(input("c = "))
t=triangle(a,b,c)
print('area of triangle is ', t.area())
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes

Answer (score -1):

```
class poly:
    def __init__(self,a,b,c):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c
        
class triangle(poly):
    def get_area(self):
        s = (self.a + self.b + self.c) / 2
        return float((s*(s-self.a)*(s-self.b)*(s-self.c))) ** 0.5        

a, b, c = float(input("a = ")), float(input("b = ")), float(input("c = "))
t = triangle(a,b,c)
print("area : {}".format(t.get_area()))
```

Comment: This is just a copy of another answer